# GPU with rootless Docker

Tags: docker, gpu

I do not want my users to have the opportunity to run their containers in privileged mode. Recently, in Docker 19.03 they introduced a rootless experimental mode. It works great, however I do not know how to combine it with a [nvidia-docker extension](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker). When I run the image with `--gpus all` flag it results in an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Is it possible to run rootless Docker with GPU?

Comment: You may have luck with the nvidia runtime: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38729

Answer (score 6):

In `/etc/nvidia-container-runtime/config.toml` under the line

```
[nvidia-container-cli]
```

add the following line:

```
no-cgroups = true
```

More Information: https://github.com/containers/libpod/issues/3659#issuecomment-543912380

Answer (score -4):

I have also met the same question. My system environment is Ubuntu 18.04 with docker 19.03. The problem was solved by the following method:

## The main reason : docker runtime need to be installed

Step1: Making a nvidia GPU check

```
$ lspci -vv | grep -i nvidia
```

Step2: Creating a file

```
$ touch nvidia-container-runtime-script.sh
```

Step3: Opening it and input the following contents

```
$ vim nvidia-container-runtime-script.sh

curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/gpgkey | \
```

sudo apt-key add -
    distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
    curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/$distribution/nvidia-container-runtime.list | \
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-runtime.list
    sudo apt-get update

Step4: Conducting the file

```
$ sh nvidia-container-runtime-script.sh
```

Step5: then

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-container-runtime
```

Step6: Checking if it is successful

```
$ which nvidia-container-runtime-hook
```

(if success it will show)/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime-hook

Step7: Restarting

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Finally: Doing what you want to do!

```
(s.t.)$docker run -it --rm --gpus all ubuntu nvidia-smi
```

Good Luck!

Comment: That doesn't appear to be rootless. In particular you are using sudo to start docker.

Comment: do you want to use commands without 'sudo' or just in your current account rather than root account? If that, the following commands should be conducted.1. $sudo groupadd docker  2.$sudo usermod -aG docker youraccountname  3.$su root 4.$su youraccountname 5.$sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R 6.$sudo chmod g+rwx "/home/$USER/.docker" -R             and then you can run commads without 'sudo'. I don't know if I understrand exactly what you mean.

Comment: Rootless is a reference to this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/